# how to index the last element of a tuple in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list of tuples that contains multiple(1 to more, number varies) tuples. For example,

```
[(5, 5), ((5, 5), (4, 5)), ((5, 5), (4, 2), (3, 3))]
```

I would like to index the last element of each tuple,

```
#ideal result
(5, 5,) (4, 5) (3, 3)
```

I have tried the following

```
 if len(n) == 1: #n is the iterator
        print n[0]
    else
        print n[-1]
```

however, for the first element, it print 5 instead of (5, 5)

Comment: The first item in the list does not contain multiple tuples/items.

Comment: @wwii thanks for pointing out, I should've mentioned that, the tuples with varied lengths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for item in theList:
    last = item[-1] # could be an int or a tuple
    if isinstance(last, tuple):
        print last
    else:
        print item
```

The key idea in this code is the `isinstance()` test. The related doco is:

**isinstance(object, classinfo)**

Return true if the object argument is an instance of the classinfo argument, or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof. Also return true if classinfo is a type object (new-style class) and object is an object of that type or of a (direct, indirect or virtual) subclass thereof. If object is not a class instance or an object of the given type, the function always returns false. If classinfo is a tuple of class or type objects (or recursively, other such tuples), return true if object is an instance of any of the classes or types. If classinfo is not a class, type, or tuple of classes, types, and such tuples, a TypeError exception is raised.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [(5, 5), ((5, 5), (4, 5)), ((5, 5), (4, 2), (3, 3))]
[ t[-1] if isinstance(t[-1], tuple) else t for t in l ]
```

Output:

```
[(5, 5), (4, 5), (3, 3)]
```